# Tables in iReport are always blank even with only static texts and they disappear when I open the file again

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

No matter the type of datasource, even if the table has only `Static Texts` it's not being rendered in the Preview. The report was compiled with success. There is data being read in the "Report query" windows (when option "Edit query" is selected and an ArrayList is loaded).

Also, when I open the JRXML file again, the table disappear.

It only works when I save the XML code on Notepad, then open it again in iReport.

Comment: How are we supposed to reproduce this? Atleast you need to add full jrxml, version of ireport, os etc. Log files would also be useful. However don't have high hopes that even with full info we are able. Try with studio?

Comment: This kind of issue also reproduced at my end with iReport. May be due to some memory consumption issue or something it was causes the issue. And this issue was only reproduced to some reports (jrxml) only. Try restarting iReport and still if it won't work, try copy your jrxml to a new report file (new jrxml file), issue should disappear. At least this works for me, creating new jrxml and copy older jrxml content to new one.

Comment: The issue was the compatibility, set to JasperReports3.5.1. Changed it to Last version and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the compatibility, set to `JasperReports3.5.1`. Changed it to `Last version` and it worked.